# How to skip a line for a title inside a node for Tikz

Tags: tikz-trees, mindmaps

I have the found a sample of a code for a concept map and I was wondering about how to skip a line. For instance,

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,shapes.geometric,arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [->,
    >=stealth',
    shorten >=1pt,
    auto,
    node distance=2cm, 
    thick,
    main node/.style={circle,fill=gray!20,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]

\node[main node,  chamfered rectangle] (1) {{\scriptsize {\tiny ODEs}}};
\node[main node] (2) [below of=1] {{\scriptsize {\tiny Euler's Equation}}};

\node[main node] (3) [right of=2] {{\scriptsize {\tiny Contrapositive}}};

\node[main node] (4) [right of=3] {{\scriptsize {\tiny direct proof}}};

\node[main node] (5) [right of=4] {{\scriptsize {\tiny test}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What could I type so as to make it double space between the title "Euler's Equation" on two lines as I dont really like how the node is so large.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `align=center` to the node specification allows you to put newlines inside node text. You also have a lot of superfluous font size commands in your nodes. Putting `\tiny` in the node style is sufficient.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,shapes.geometric,arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [->,
    >=stealth',
    shorten >=1pt,
    auto,
    node distance=2cm, 
    thick,
    main node/.style={circle,fill=gray!20,draw,font=\sffamily\bfseries\tiny,align=center}]

\node[main node,  chamfered rectangle] (1) { ODEs};
\node[main node] (2) [below of=1] {Euler’s\\Equation};

\node[main node] (3) [right of=2] {Contrapositive};

\node[main node] (4) [right of=3] {direct proof};

\node[main node] (5) [right of=4] {test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Using `\node[main node, align=center] (2) [below of=1] {Euler’s\\Equation};` works perfectly here... (btw there is a `\Large` which does nothing in the `font` key)

Comment: @Rmano thanks. I've changed the answer as it does work with my answer (as it should). But if you try the OPs original code, (with the extra `{}` and font commands inside) it doesn't.